# Trying to prove that two angles are congruent in a isosceles trapezoid

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, proof-verification, quadrilateral

I was given this assignment to do the following.

> Write a paragraph proof for the following scenario.
>
> Given: $ KLMN $ is an isosceles trapezoid.
>
> Prove: $ \angle LKM \cong \angle MNL $

The thing is that I think I successfully did this, but the actual answer is way different from mine. It’s more complicated, actually. I’d like someone to please review this and tell me if:

1. Is this proof correct?
2. If not, then why not?

[image]

The handwritten text above is:

> It is given that $ KLN $ is an isosceles trapezoid. Both $ \overline{ LK } $ and $ \overline{ MN } $ are congruent due to the definition of an isosceles trapezoid. $ \angle L $ and $ \angle M $ are congruent; angles on the either sides of the bases of an isosceles trapezoid are congruent is a property.<sup>*1*</sup> Vertical angle theorem states that vertical angles are congruent, so angles X and Y are congruent. $ \triangle LXH \cong \triangle MYN $ due to AAS.<sup>*2*</sup> $ \angle K \cong \angle N $, because corresponding parts of congruent triangles are congruent.

<sup>*1*</sup><sub>Originally transcribed by OP as *is another property as well*</sub>

<sup>*2*</sup><sub>Amplified in original transcription by OP to *Angle-Angle-Side Theorem*</sub>

Comment: I think that you wanted to conclude that $\angle KLM = \angle NML$, not that $\angle KLN = \angle NMK$ (I don't see why $\angle KLN = \angle NMK$ follows). You can still carry your idea through, but you have to prove a different pair of triangles congrument.

Comment: @Rogerl Actually, what I wrote is exactly what I want to do. I copied that part of the question from my lesson on an online course.

Comment: If the lesson said $\angle L = \angle M$, which angles do you think it meant? (In your picture, $\angle L$ is ambiguous, as is $\angle M$.)

Comment: @Rogerl That's not what my lesson said. I figured that out, because it is a property of isosceles trapezoids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start correctly with "both $\overline{LK}$ and $\overline{MN}$ are congruent". (As a style point, in UK usage you would phrase this "The lines $\overline{LK}$ and $\overline{MN}$ are equal in length." It's a bit clearer to keep "congruent" for referring to triangles or other two-or-more-dimensional shapes.)

The other property you are given is that $\angle L$ and $\angle M$ are equal. This means that the angles between the edges of the trapezoid are at those corners are equal, $\widehat{KLM}=\widehat{LMN}$. But none of your working mentions these angles clearly and you don't mark them on any of your diagrams. So this is where your answer starts going wrong.

(Finally, and after the error: the sentence "angles on the either sides of the bases of an isosceles trapezoid are congruent is another property as well" doesn't make much sense to me. Do you mean "$\angle N = \angle K$"? That's easily proved using "alternate angles".)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistakes, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Provided you are allowed to state that $\angle{KLM}=\angle{NML}$, the rest is easy.  Consider triangle $\triangle{KLM}$ and $\triangle{NML}$.  Both share side $\overline{LM}$.  By definition of "isosceles", the sides of the trapezoid are equal.  Hence $\overline{KL}=\overline{NM}$.  Thus, via SAS (side angle side), $\triangle{KLM}$ and $\triangle{NML}$ are congruent.  Finally, since corresponding angles of congruent triangles are equal, we have $\angle{LKM}=\angle{MNL}$.

Comment: The questioner asked what was wrong with his attempted proof, not how to prove it.